# Varnish ESI with Wordpress 3.5 Widget

Tags: wordpress, nginx, widget, varnish, esi

I am trying to use Varnish ESI statements to avoid the cache on a single Wordpress Widget.

I've found a good guide explaining the process for using ESI for the entire sidebar here: http://timbroder.com/2012/12/getting-started-with-varnish-edge-side-includes-and-wordpress.html but having difficulties trying to work out how it's done for single widgets.

Other details:

- **Site URL:** livefeeedietravelling (dot com)
- **Varnish:** 3.0.3 Wordpress
- **Version:** 3.5
- **Server:** nginx/1.2.6 (with APC)

Answer (score 0):

Resolved the issue by including a text widget which had the ESI code linking to an external php script containing the output to the widget content I wanted to serve. Simple really.